# Checking for sole ownership of shared_ptr

Tags: c++11, thread-safety, smart-pointers, race-condition

I have often had the desire to check to see if a `shared_ptr` was the only owner of a shared object.  It would be convenient for handing off behaviors before destroying the last shared_ptr, instead of having to do if after the destruction (my particular use case was dealing with preservation of weak pointers by rescuing them with another `shared_ptr` before destruction.  After destruction has started, it's too late to rescue them).

> C++11[draft] 20.7.2.1.4:
>
> For purposes of determining the presence of a data race, member
>   functions shall access and modify only the shared_ptr and weak_ptr
>   objects themselves and not objects they refer to. Changes in
>   use_count() do not reflect modifications that can introduce data
>   races.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28113769/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-piece-of-standardese-about-shared-ptrs-use-count) clarified a concern I had had about `p.use_count() == 1` causing a data race.  However, I am still not convinced it is safe to use in the way I want to use it.

In a single-threaded world, if `use_count()` returns 1, then you know you're the last owner of that object.  In a multithreading world where you've avoided data races, it seems reasonable that `use_count()` of 1 is sufficient to ensure you are the sole owner, but I'm having a frustrating time trying to get that from the spec-eese.  I can't tell if there's some loophole that would permit a use_count of 1 even though another shared_ptr exists on another thread.  On the other hand, it seems frustrating that the definition of `use_count` might turn to goo just beacuse I handed a shared_ptr to another thread.

Can I ever get into a situation where `use_count()` is 1, but I am not the only owner, by the rules of the spec?  I recognize that, thanks to races, a `use_count` of 2 does not explicitly mean I am sharing (the other thread might release my object after my call to `use_count` on this thread), but I'm interested in the other direction, once I have seen `use_count` of 1.

As a second related question: do the same rules apply for `unique`, which seems to be custom tailored to my desired implementation, but does not have any extra statements made regarding thread safety?

---

**Edit:** In response to answers I've gotten, the situation I am interested in has the `shared_ptr` we are calling `unique_count` on is only accessible by a single thread, so I do not have to worry about any other thread successfully copying it... they have to find their own `shared_ptr` to copy!

Comment: Please be aware that you don't need another thread to copy the `shared_ptr` you are going to release, but it is enough that another thread copies a `shared_ptr` or creates a `shared_ptr` from a `weak_ptr` that *shares ownership* with the `shared_ptr` you are going to release. As you say there are `weak_ptr`s around, so @Barry is right by pointing out that `use_count` may return 1, but after seeing the value, another thread might have used a `weak_ptr` to create another reference.

Answer (score 4):

If there is a possibility that a `weak_ptr` exists that points to the same control block as your single `shared_ptr`, and if another thread might convert that `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr`, then your thread could observe a `use_count() == 1`, but by the time it can do anything with that information, the other thread may construct a new `shared_ptr` from the `weak_ptr`, bumping the `use_count` up to 2.

Even if there are no `weak_ptr`s, if more than one thread has read access to your `shared_ptr` (e.g. say its a global), then another thread might make a copy of it after you observe `use_count() == 1`.

If your `shared_ptr` is not accessible to any other thread, and there is no possibility that another thread might convert a `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr`, then `use_count() == 1` is safe to depend on.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Even if it were specified that `use_count()` and `unique()` were both atomic, and it doesn't:

> `long use_count() const noexcept;`
>   *Returns:* the number of `shared_ptr` objects, `*this` included, that share ownership with `*this`, or 0
>   when `*this` is empty.
>   *[ Note:* `use_count()` is not necessarily efficient.*—end note ]*
>
> `bool unique() const noexcept;`
>   *Returns:* `use_count() == 1`.
>   *[ Note:* `unique()` may be faster than `use_count()`. If you are using `unique()` to implement copy on
>   write, do not rely on a specific value when `get() == nullptr`. *—end note ]*

There's nothing to stop something like this happening:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> sp;

// thread 1                      // thread 2    
bool uniq = sp.unique();    /**/
                            /**/   std::shared_ptr<Foo> cpy = sp;
if (uniq) {                 /**/
   /* mine?? */             /**/   cpy->foo();
   /* nope :-( */           /**/
}                           /**/
```