# Is reference counting thread safe

Tags: c++, multithreading

For example consider

```
class ProcessList {
private
   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeObject>> list;
   Mutex mutex;
public:
   void Add(std::shared_ptr<SomeObject> o) { 
       Locker locker(&mutex); // Start of critical section. Locker release so will the mutex - In house stuff
       list.push_back(std::make_shared<SomeObject>(o).
   }

   void Remove(std::shared_ptr<SomeObject> o) { 
       Locker locker(&mutex); // Start of critical section. Locker release so will the mutex - In house stuff
       // Code to remove said object but indirectly modifying the reference count in copy below
   }

   void Process() {
       std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeObject>> copy;

       {
           Locker locker(&mutes);
           copy = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeObject>>(
                list.begin(), list.end()
           )
       }
       for (auto it = copy.begin(), it != copy.end(); ++it) {
           it->Procss(); // This may take time/add/remove to the list
       }
    }
};
```

One thread runs `Process`. Multiple threads run add/remove.

Will the reference count be safe and always correct - or should a mutex be placed around that?

Comment: Reference counting can be implemented thread-safely. Considering that you have C++11 which also has threads, I'd assume that refcounting is also implemented in a thread-safe way. BTW: Even the original `shared_ptr` from Boost was already thread-safe.

Comment: Does each reference count have a mutex?

Comment: No, they use atomic operations. You could implement them using a mutex for every counter, but that would be inefficient. You could also implement them using a single global mutex, which would be simpler, but probably still less efficient than using atomics.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt does the standard mandate that this is the case (that `shared_ptr` is thread safe)? If so could you give a reference? Thanks.

Comment: On https://duckduckgo.com/?q=C%2B%2B+shared_ptr+thread+safe this is answered by the first link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::shared\_ptr thread safety](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482830/stdshared-ptr-thread-safety)

Comment: [Another near-dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28113769/179910).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the standard (at §20.8.2.2, at least as of N3997) that's intended to require that the reference counting be thread-safe.

For your simple cases like `Add`:

```
void Add(std::shared_ptr<SomeObject> o) { 
    Locker locker(&mutex);
    list.push_back(std::make_shared<SomeObject>(o).
}
```

...the guarantees in the standard are strong enough that you shouldn't need the mutex, so you can just have:

```
void Add(std::shared_ptr<SomeObject> o) { 
    list.push_back(std::make_shared<SomeObject>(o).
}
```

For some of your operations, it's not at all clear that thread-safe reference counting necessarily obviates your mutex though. For example, inside of your `Process`, you have:

```
   {
       Locker locker(&mutes);
       copy = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeObject>>(
            list.begin(), list.end()
       )
   }
```

This carries out the entire copy as an atomic operation--nothing else can modify the list during the copy. This assures that your copy gives you a snapshot of the list precisely as it was when the copy was started. If you eliminate the mutex, the reference counting will still work, *but* your copy might reflect changes made while the copy is being made.

In other words, the thread safety of the `shared_ptr` only assures that each individual increment or decrement is atomic--it doesn't assure that manipulations of the entire list are atomic as the mutex does in this case.

Since your `list` is actually a `vector`, you should be able to simplify the copying code a bit to just `copy = list`.

Also note that your `Locker` seems to be a subset of what `std::lock_guard` provides. It appears you could use:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(&mutes);
```

...in its place quite easily.

Comment: But is the vector thread safe as well? I think that it is not so there is an interaction between the two. Anyway our locker does a little extra in terms of logging.

Comment: @EdHeal: There's nothing to prohibit a vector implementation from providing thread safety, but it's not required either. If multiple threads modify the vector, then yes, you need to use a mutex (or whatever) to serialize that access.

Comment: It is a vector of shared pointers. - so the items are safe but the vector is not - is that correct

Comment: @EdHeal: that's the idea, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It will be an overhead to have a mutex for reference counting.

Internally, mutexes use atomic operations, basically a mutex does internal thread safe reference counting. So you can just use atomics for your reference counting directly instead of using a mutex and essentially doing double the work.

Answer (score -2):

Unless your CPU architecture have an atomic increment/decrement and you used that for reference count, then, no, it's not safe; C++ makes no guarantee on the thread safety of x++/x-- operation on any of its standard types.

Use `atomic<int>` if your compiler supports them (C++11), otherwise you'll need to have the lock.

Further references:

- https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/Atomic_Operations.htm

Comment: The question is whether `std::shared_ptr` (which is what is being used in the code provided by OP) is threadsafe. There is no "x++/x--" operation here (unless it's in the shared_ptr implementation).